# Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in C:\User..\ on 148

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm inserting a new column collegename, branch, and gender but suddenly it's giving me this error...

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of 
parameters in prepared statement in C:\Users\Raj\PhpstormProjects\usercake\models
\class.newuser.php on line 148
```

What's that mean?

Actually I was inserting a new column into my database `college`, `branch`, `year`, and `gender` everything goes well but when I register myself it's shows the message your Registration is successfully submitted but suddenly it shows this error message as wells as?

Here is my source code:

```
<?php
class User 
{
    public $user_active = 0;
    private $clean_email;
    public $status = false;
    private $clean_password;
    private $username;
    private $displayname;
    public $sql_failure = false;
    public $mail_failure = false;
    public $email_taken = false;
    public $username_taken = false;
    public $displayname_taken = false;
    public $activation_token = 0;
    public $success = NULL;
    
    function __construct($user,$display,$pass,$email)
    {
        //Used for display only
        $this->displayname = $display;
        
        //Sanitize
        $this->clean_email = sanitize($email);
        $this->clean_password = trim($pass);
        $this->username = sanitize($user);
        
        if(usernameExists($this->username))
        {
            $this->username_taken = true;
        }
        else if(displayNameExists($this->displayname))
        {
            $this->displayname_taken = true;
        }
        else if(emailExists($this->clean_email))
        {
            $this->email_taken = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //No problems have been found.
            $this->status = true;
        }
    }
    
    public function userCakeAddUser()
    {
        global $mysqli,$emailActivation,$websiteUrl,$db_table_prefix;
        
        //Prevent this function being called if there were construction errors
        if($this->status)
        {
            //Construct a secure hash for the plain text password
            $secure_pass = generateHash($this->clean_password);
            
            //Construct a unique activation token
            $this->activation_token = generateActivationToken();
            
            //Do we need to send out an activation email?
            if($emailActivation == "true")
            {
                //User must activate their account first
                $this->user_active = 0;
                
                $mail = new userCakeMail();
                
                //Build the activation message
                $activation_message = lang("ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_MESSAGE",array($websiteUrl,$this->activation_token));
                
                //Define more if you want to build larger structures
                $hooks = array(
                    "searchStrs" => array("#ACTIVATION-MESSAGE","#ACTIVATION-KEY","#USERNAME#"),
                    "subjectStrs" => array($activation_message,$this->activation_token,$this->displayname)
                    );
                
                /* Build the template - Optional, you can just use the sendMail function 
                Instead to pass a message. */
                
                if(!$mail->newTemplateMsg("new-registration.txt",$hooks))
                {
                    $this->mail_failure = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Send the mail. Specify users email here and subject. 
                    //SendMail can have a third parementer for message if you do not wish to build a template.
                    
                    if(!$mail->sendMail($this->clean_email,"New User"))
                    {
                        $this->mail_failure = true;
                    }
                }
                $this->success = lang("ACCOUNT_REGISTRATION_COMPLETE_TYPE2");
            }
            else
            {
                //Instant account activation
                $this->user_active = 1;
                $this->success = lang("ACCOUNT_REGISTRATION_COMPLETE_TYPE1");
            }   
            
            
            if(!$this->mail_failure)
            {
                //Insert the user into the database providing no errors have been found.
                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$db_table_prefix."users (
                    user_name,
                    display_name,
                    password,
                    email,
                    college,
                    branch,
                    year,
                    gender,
                    activation_token,
                    last_activation_request,
                    lost_password_request, 
                    active,
                    title,
                    sign_up_stamp,
                    last_sign_in_stamp
                    )
                    VALUES (
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    '".time()."',
                    '0',
                    ?,
                    'New Member',
                    '".time()."',
                    '0'
                    )");
                
                $stmt->bind_param("sssssi", $this->username, $this->displayname, $secure_pass, $this->clean_email, $this->activation_token, $this->user_active);
                $stmt->execute();
                $inserted_id = $mysqli->insert_id;
                $stmt->close();
                
                //Insert default permission into matches table
                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$db_table_prefix."user_permission_matches  (
                    user_id,
                    permission_id
                    )
                    VALUES (
                    ?,
                    '1'
                    )");
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $inserted_id);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: didn't you ask the same question recently?

Comment: You have more `?` than params given.

Comment: It means just what it says: Your query doesn't match the arguments you supply. You are only supplying 6 arguments, but there are way more placeholders (`?`).

Comment: I'm giving you a -1. Reason: a message such as this is easily understandable. I am saying that because I talk from experience - I had the very same error message years before, I was able to resolve it on my own without going to a website and spending time asking questions. It tells you that number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in the statement. WHAT is the ONLY thing you will do at that point and why is it go and count number of parameters and variables you've bound and executed at that line? This is pure laziness, if you won't invest time debugging then what's the point?

Comment: @DrColossos: i guess not...

Comment: @user3531220 did you even actually write all this code yourself..?

Comment: You have 10 `?` but `sssssi` is not 10 characters....

Comment: BTW; posting the same question twice with a different title won't solve the problem either....

Comment: I find PDO much easier to use

Comment: @DrColossos: so how much i should use?.

Comment: @DrColossos: will you please post your answer exactly? :( don't take it personally i mean i still don't understand this....

Comment: @user3531220 there is plenty of documentation available on this subject. Go ahead and read about it! This way, you will learn much more.

Answer (score 1):

You have 10 ? in your prepare statement but you passed 6 variables to it on $stmt->bind_param. You must pass exactly same variables as you have in statement. Your bind must be something like this:

```
$stmt->bind_param('isisississ', $int1, $str1, $int2, $str2, $int3, $str3, $str4, $int4, $str5, $str6);
```